# Display product custom field in WooCommerce Order admin Page (ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

With WooCommerce, I'm using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to Add product design URL

I tide this code to display "design_url"

```
// Display on orders and email notifications (save as custom order item meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_acf_on_orders_and_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_acf_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $plant  = get_field( 'plant', $values['product_id'] );
    $amount = get_field( 'amount', $values['product_id'] );

    if ( ! empty($plant) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("Size", "woocommerce"), $plant );
    }

    if ( ! empty($amount) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("Amount", "woocommerce"), $amount );
    }
}
```

But I want display it only on order Admin page

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'display_acf_on_order_admin_page', 10, 3 );
function display_acf_on_order_admin_page( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $plant  = get_field( 'plant', $product_id );
    $amount = get_field( 'amount', $product_id );

    if ( ! empty( $plant ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Size', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . $plant . '</p>';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $amount ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Amount', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . $amount . '</p>';
    }
}
```

This function will be called for each order item in the order, and it will display the "plant" and "amount" custom field values if they are present.

Comment: Thanks so much, but it's still showing in email and thank you page

Comment: The hook you are calling in your example `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` is copying the acf field value from product to order item meta. Try to comment out your custom code and create a new order.